# Liferay service builder and jsp form portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I've created my database and using service builder and now I want to create portlet which will be form to add some entity. I dont know how to use created dto in jsp and how do i  persist user input  to database.

Do I have to init dto class in jsp?

I will appreciate any help, especially examples.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this project](http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/).  They support exactly the type of thing you are trying to do.  It generates CRUD pages for any service builder entity.  Actually it will generate the whole portlet including CRUD pages.  It will handle everything from userinput all the way through the layers to the database.

Comment: I'm already using service builder, so changing now to another solution is impossible. But this is interesting alternative, thanks!

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  However, you could install that framework and go through some examples.  Then you can see the code that it generates and just copy and paste over the code that goes through the layers and apply them to your ServiceBuilder code.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5

hope it will help you.